# Django: Attach passed id to instance?

Tags: django

I am trying to attach the id I pass through my query string to an instance of a form field user_id. I have tried many different ways and can't seem to get it to work.  The id IS being passed successfully.

urls for how I passed it (tried int: still didn't work)

```
 path('customer_note/<id>', views.customer_note, name='customer-note'),
```

views

```
def customer_note(request, id):
      obj_instance = Customer.objects.get(user_id= id)
      obj_instance.user_id = id
      obj_instance.save(update_fields=['user_id',])
#this is the start of the form save. I couldn't figure out how to do it here either.
      if request.method =="POST":
            customer_form =    CustomerForm(request.POST)
            if customer_form.is_valid():
      . . .
```

Thank you

I have tried using request.user.customer.id and attaching it. I have tried update() in various ways.

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. What do you mean by "attaching an id" to an instance? I'm confused why you need to set the user_id to the same user_id you just used to query the Customer model.

Comment: your model is unclear. if customer is an instance that has user in its attributes why are you trying to set user_id ?? If you want change change user attribute after obj_instance.user_id = id you only need to save: obj_instance.save(). if you have error what is that?

Comment: Getting customer with the user_id from the request query and again updating it to the same? What the point of this API? The update will change nothing.

Comment: "attaching an id" or saving the passed number to an instance of user_id. 1. I have a logged on Employee. 2. That EMployee can create multiple notes for a customer. 3. After they create a note, I pass the customer's id, I am trying to attach it to the form instance, so in the database the customer's id, from User, get's saved to the PK user_id in the Customer table.

Comment: WOW. Thank you, your responses made me think more clearly about this. It didn't work because Customer had a FK linked to User. I needed to create a new model with a FK linked to Customer for it to work. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The Comments made me realize this, but they didn't explain this well.

I can't accomplish this because Customers has a FK with Users. This would create data redundancy with user id's. To fix this I needed a table not linked to Users. This table could have a FK to Customers.